# TextBoxFor default value and keep edited value after validation fail

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Razor code like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name, new { @Value = student.t_Name })
```

and I using .NET MVC's model validation in Controller,

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("B");
    }
    else 
    {
        return View(); // when validation failed
    }
```

My situation is I have a edit function, for example:
original data:

```
birthday: 1992-05-26
```

after edited:

```
birthday: 1992-05-32
```

after I submit this to Controller and make model validation, it will validate fail, and return to previous view(the view before form submit),
I want it shows

```
birthday:1992-05-32
```

instead of

```
birthday:1992-05-26
```

Comment: add model to view when return view ` return View(yourmodel);`

Comment: do you want original value in only birthday field?

Comment: and can you show your model?

Comment: NEVER set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods unless you want to ensure binding fails. Set the value of your property in the GET method before you pass the model to the view - `model.Name = student.t_Name`

Comment: Remove all your ` new { value = ... }` attributes and it will work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set ViewModel values that come to your controller like this:

```
public ActionResult YourControllerMethod(YourViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("B");
    }
    else 
    {
        ViewData.Model = model; //where model is your controller model
        return View(); // when validation failed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass the current posted model instance back to view when returning back View something like:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(SomeModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     return RedirectToAction("B");
   }
   else 
   {
    return View(model);
   }

}
```